# How to create & execute a script file

Tags: command-line, scripts

Is there a way to create and execute a script file in Ubuntu 14.04?  Perhaps something like Windows batch files.  Specifically, I mean the default scripting language of the Ubuntu terminal (Bash).  How do you make a text file containing bash commands which will be run by the Ubuntu terminal from the top of the file to the bottom.

Comment: Of course, most people use bash scripts, but you can use perl, python, awk ... See http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your "shell" or the command line interface is called bash. You can write a bash script which is similar to a batch file. A bash script starts with a She-bang `#!/bin/bash` and is nothing more then a set of commands to run in a sequence to run them. You are not limited to bash command, you can call any binary on the system by using the full path to the binary or script.

A master thread on learning/books/terminal/bash/Linux etc
Linux Command Line Learning Resources - cortman
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources

My first bash was several commands I was running multiple times in terminal. So I listed history with history command and copied them into text file. First line must be this (no spaces before it and first line):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And after saving you must make it executeable.

```
sudo chmod +x <path>
sudo chmod 755 <filename>
```

Note that it is a good idea to put your scripts in one place, so you can run them without requiring a path. If you create a bin directory in your home ( mkdir ~/bin ) the next time you login, that will automatically be included in your PATH.

```
mkdir ~/bin
chmod 755 ~/bin
```

Edit : If you want the script to be available to all users, place it in /usr/local/bin and have it owned by root with rx access by others `sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/your_script ; sudo chmod 655 /usr/local/bin/your_script`

```
gksudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following to the end of .bashrc and save:

```
if [ -d $HOME/bin ]; then
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
fi
```

Comment: @Strato1 bash scripts are most common, but Lucio raises a very valid point, one can use a long list of languages. They syntax is the same, start with a She-bang and list commands. Careful how you google search She-bang ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Comment: I do mean Bash scripts. I have updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: Needs more explanation.