# Can't run Bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a simple Bash script called `deploy-site.sh` (by http://klau.si/dev). I made the necessary edits to run it locally (change of WORKDIR, etc). I also followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471285/how-to-create-execute-a-script-file).

```
mkdir ~/bin
chmod 755 ~/bin
```

(To store the script in my home folder. Then I rebooted, so the system recognizes it.)

```
sudo chmod +x <path>
sudo chmod 755 <filename>
```

However, whenever I go to the terminal to execute the Bash script, I get:

```
$ sudo deploy-site.sh <sitename>
sudo: deploy-site.sh: command not found
```

How can I fix this problem?

---

Here is the original script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 || $1 == "--help" || $1 == "-h" ]]
then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "  sudo `basename $0` SITENAME"
  echo "Examples:"
  echo "  sudo `basename $0` drupal-8"
  exit
fi

WORKDIR="/home/klausi/workspace"
APACHEDIR="/etc/apache2/sites-available"
HOSTSFILE="/etc/hosts"

echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias $1.localhost
    DocumentRoot $WORKDIR/$1
    <Directory \"$WORKDIR/$1\">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>" > $APACHEDIR/$1.conf
a2ensite $1
service apache2 restart
grep -q "127.0.0.1  $1.localhost" $HOSTSFILE
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "127.0.0.1  $1.localhost" >> $HOSTSFILE
fi
```

As requested, here is the results of echo `$PATH`

/home/getoprodigy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Just because you  add it to `~/bin` and reboot doesn't mean that the system recognizes it - you need to add it your `PATH`.

Comment: Add output of `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: Please run `echo $PATH` to see if the directory does not appear in $PATH for some reason. @Wilf it should be in $PATH after log out/in or running `source ~/.profile`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm not if run with `sudo`... :)

Comment: @Wilf aargh, that's why one shouldn't visit AU on a small smartphone :)

Answer (score 14):

`deploy-site.sh` is not in PATH. You have to run it as `./deploy-site.sh` if you are in the same directory or `/path/deploy-site.sh` if not

Comment: Just to mention: `~/bin` should be in `$PATH` if the directory exists and after log out or running `source ~/.profile`.

Answer (score 8):

To run it as `deploy-site.sh` you need to add it to your [`$PATH`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PATHREF) - you can view your current path with `echo $PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$
```

<sup>↑ standard path on Ubuntu 14.04 (probably)</sup>

You can a few things to 'fix' it:

- **Run it from the current directory**:

  ```
  wget http://klau.si/sites/default/files/deploy-site.sh_.txt -O deploy-site.sh
  sudo ./deploy-site.sh
  ```
- **Add it to a existing directory PATH**: As above you can view the existing path with `echo $PATH`, and add it to one of the directories to make it work - for custom commands that you want to run system-wide `/usr/local/bin` usually suffices.

  ```
  wget http://klau.si/sites/default/files/deploy-site.sh_.txt -O deploy-site
  sudo cp deploy-site /usr/local/bin/
  sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/
  sudo deploy-site
  ```
- **Add the directory to the PATH**: Normal practice too add it permanently would be to add this to `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` etc:

  ```
  #.bash_profile

  # Get the aliases and functions
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] ; then
  . ~/.bashrc
  fi

  #User specific environment and startup programs
  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

  export PATH
  ```

  BUT this only works for your current user (not when run with `sudo`).
  To make it work with `sudo` (i.e. the `root` user) ou should be able to make in a similar way by (CAREFULLY) modifying `/etc/environment` (or possibly `/root/.profile` etc), but as this script looks like it only need to be run once, I would recommend one of the above methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it by

```
sudo bash deploy-site.sh
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense, because there is already a shebang in the script.

Comment: still should work - I don't think it needs the `./` or to executable permission then as well.

Comment: I see down-votes and delete flag, please explain why before voting down or deleting this answer, I am sure it works and I use this way, you can see it as  a hint in http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html

Comment: for all those concerned this answer works perfectly...  but adding the bash command seems to be an extra step... anyway I can run script with the bash as designed?

Answer (score 2):

You are just changing the file permission. To run the script you can specify full pathname as tikend's answer.

If you want to use it as a command from any directory,  create a link in `/usr/bin` and you can use the link as command.

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo ln /path/to/your/script linkname
```

now you can type `linkname` from any directory.

Comment: make the symlink, but can't run from any directory.  still requires a path to execute

Comment: did you try the the script's filename or the linkname. you have to use the `linkname` as command now.

Comment: but what is the `link name`?

Comment: linkname is whatever you want your command to be called by. you fill it in.