# run batch file in startup with ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

i want to create a batch file.
this batch file will run my browser after sleep again run it.
something like

```
start firefox.exe
sleep 10
start firefox.exe
```

But the question is how i add this batch file to the startup of ubuntu

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972343/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-and-run-it

Comment: yes but add on startup. how will be

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/q/63407/66509