# Whys isn't my linux bash working

Tags: bash

I have the following file, named `set_env_lin.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SLACK_WEBHOOK_DEV=some_value_1
export SLACK_WEBHOOK_REAL=some_value_2
```

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972343/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-and-run-it#:%7E:text=Batch%20file%20equivalent%20in%20linux%20is%20shell%20script,one.%20A%20good%20start%20for%20begginers%20is%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tldp.org%2FLDP%2FBash-Beginners-Guide%2Fhtml%2Findex.html.) to make it a bash file, but when y call `echo $SLACK_WEBHOOK_REAL`, I get no value set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want the exported variables to be visible in the parent shell, the file must be *sourced* (`. set_env_lin.sh` or `source set_env_lin.sh`) rather than simply run

Comment: When you `./set_env_lin.sh`, `bash` creates a process, sets up redirections, and starts `bash` in that process to interpret your script. Your script adds the environment variable settings to the process's environment.  When your script finishes, the process exits, and it's environment (with your changes) is discarded. Like @steeldriver says, you must `source` the file. `source` interprets the script in the current shell. Once the environment variable changes are added to the current shell,  they'll be passed on to processes started by the current shell.

Comment: @waltinator  Might as well make that comment the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `./set_env_lin.sh`, `bash` creates a process, sets up redirections, and starts `/bin/bash` in that process to interpret your script. Your script adds the environment variable settings to the process's environment. When your script finishes, the process exits, and its environment (with your changes) is discarded. Like @steeldriver: says, you must `source` the file. `source` interprets the script in the current shell. Once the environment variable changes are added to the current shell, they'll be passed on to processes started by the current shell.