# Freeing up Ubuntu system resources?

Tags: scripts, cron, ubuntu-tweak, user-mode-linux

I have an old laptop I run Ubuntu on. However the capacity of this pc is small, so I have to clean often. But opening the file with the commands, copying and pasting into the terminal, gets boring quick. How do I execute a clean cron script, if the system reaches a threshold of 90% ... freeing up system memory and resources ???.

Comment: I copied commands into a script to both update & houseclean. https://askubuntu.com/questions/471285/how-to-create-execute-a-script-file/471286#471286  I prefer to manually run script, so I can see exactly what is changing. If lightweight system, you may need a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)